# 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found (CocoaPods)

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm going back to a React Native project and getting the following build error:

```
'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found
```

The project uses CocoaPods to bring in React and its dependencies. The error seems to be to do with a missing header in one of my custom modules. The specific line with the import error is at https://github.com/adamski/react-native-couchbase/blob/8bc089a1e4cfdf62599b1f156072aa12a3823b30/ios/RCTCouchBase/RCTCouchBase/RCTCouchBase.h#L8

The error only started to appear after adding a new node module and running `pod install`.

I've have tried various things to fix it such as:

- Upgrading RN (from 0.51 to 0.55 and back again)
- Deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`
- Adding various paths to Header Search Paths. e.g. `${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React`
- Deleting Build folder

If I change the import to `#import "RCTEventEmitter"` it then falls over on:

`'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found` **from RCTEventEmitter.h**.

Anything else that could be going wrong here?

I recently had to upgrade to Xcode 10 for another project, perhaps that is an issue?

Podfile:

```
react_native_path = '../../node_modules/react-native'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'MyApp - App' do

    pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 4.1.3'

    pod 'React', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
        'ART',
        'Core',
        'RCTImage',    
        'RCTLinkingIOS',
        'RCTNetwork',
        'RCTText',
        'RCTWebSocket',
        'RCTAnimation',
        'DevSupport',
        'BatchedBridge',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
    ]
    # To use CocoaPods with React Native, you need to add this specific Yoga spec as well
    pod 'yoga', :path => react_native_path + '/ReactCommon/yoga'

    pod 'couchbase-lite-ios', '~> 1.4.0' 
    pod 'couchbase-lite-ios/ForestDB', '~> 1.4.0'
    pod 'mp3lame-for-ios'
    pod 'ReactNativeCouchbase',      :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-couchbase'
    pod 'ReactNativeNavigation',     :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-navigation'
    pod 'RNVectorIcons',             :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
    pod 'RNSVG',                     :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-svg'
    pod 'RNDeviceInfo',              :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
    pod 'react-native-in-app-utils', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-in-app-utils'
    pod 'react-native-mail',         :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-mail'
    pod 'BVLinearGradient',          :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
    pod 'RNSound',                   :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-sound'
    pod 'react-native-youtube',      :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-youtube'
    pod 'RNStoreReview',             :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-store-review/ios'

end
```

Comment: Can you add your pod file?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Podfile added

Comment: Try using `CxxBridge` and other podspecs as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies)

Comment: @PritishVaidya I tried that, `pod install` clean, build, same error..